# How can I send Notification new message arrived to user by SignalR Hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

In our MVC 4 web, I want the system send a notification to user each time he receive a new message. So when there is a changing in my database (example: a new row is added to table), the system will send user a notification?

Comment: I m also looking to something like this. any luck?

Comment: Im also looking the same....

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps to do so:

1. Follow the instruction on [signalR wiki page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) to create a hub called myhub
2. For each connection you have a connection id which you can use to relate to userid or you can even pass username as a parameter to your hub methods. Again read the above page. you can add any parameter to the methods on hub.
3. Create a method on both server and client to notifynewmessage.
4. Serverside method should take a parameter of connection ID or username.
5. Client side method should simply populate your new message section or update number of new messages.
6. When a user recives a message and you have inserted into DB or recieved it on hub alone without any persistence you can send this message to a single client by connection ID. This time you might not send the full message and just something like messagecountupdate or newmessage excerpt.
7. The above will go on notifynewmessage at client and happy days

If you need a ready made solution or a working example I would suggest fork an existing singalR repo on github or create a new MVC 4 app and put it in a project on github. Any issues after you have tried something will convince more people to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message from a hub from anywhere in your application. Look at 
"Broadcasting over a Hub from outside of a Hub"  on https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

Basically using this approach you can send notifications to all clients..